# App hosting on Facebook

Tags: facebook, hosting

I have just created an app on Facebook and my app is hosted on heroku. All my PHP files and HTML files are uploaded to the Heroku server. The URL to my app is http://appname.herokuapp.com.

Now how do I make that available on Facebook? What I want is a link on Facebook that will make my application appear on Facebook.

Is it also possible to publish my app on Facebook, anyone can just type my app name on the AJAX text-field and it pops out.

I do have my appname name visible on my home-page under apps section but when I click on it, it takes me to the app settings page.

Anyone has hosted apps on Facebook and can point me in the right direction?